# Feed Bazel output to another Bazel rule

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am pretty new to Bazel and have a difficult time figuring out a solution for this:

Say I have this `nodejs_binary` rule:

```
nodejs_binary(
    name = "js_scirpt",
    data = [
        "@npm//some_lib",
    ],
    entry_point = ":some_js_script.js",
)
```

Now I need the output from `:js_script` be fed to a `go_test` rule which does something else. The sequence matters: nodejs rule should finishes first and then go_test uses the output.

I think this should be possible by writing a `json` file from the `nodejs_binary` to the disk and read it from `some_js_script.js`, though I cannot control the sequence of executions and I don't know how to pass it to `go_test` rule. Any idea on how this is possible (or maybe there is a better approach)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [dependency](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#dependencies) is the way to make one thing happen before another with Bazel. [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule) is the easiest way to run a command and have the output available.

Putting them together looks like this:

```py
genrule(
    name = "run_js_script",
    tools = [
        ":js_script",
    ],
    outs = [
        "something.json",
    ],
    cmd = "$(location :js_script) --output $(location something.json)",
)

go_test(
    data = [
        ":something.json",
    ],
    [name, srcs, deps, etc]
)
```

The Go code should use [runfiles.go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/tools/bazel/runfiles.go) to find the path to the file.

Also, the Node code should take a command-line flag for the destination to write its output. If it can't do that, then use shell commands to move the output to `$(location something.json)`.

Comment: Thank you Brian - genrule was my first try as well. The issue with it is for some reason it doesn't find nodejs dependencies. For example I will get `Error: Cannot find module "@npm//some_lib"` in your example.

Comment: That looks like a problem with your `nodejs_binary`. I'm not familiar with the nodejs rules unfortunately. Try getting `bazel run //:js_script` to work before trying to feed the output into another rule, if you need help ask another question about only that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `nodejs_binary` or `go_test`, but what you probably want is the test to depend on the nodejs binary through the `data` attribute: 
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/core.rst#go-test 
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#data

```
go_test(
    name = "go_default_test",
    srcs = ["some_test.go"],
    data = [":js_script"],
)
```

`js_scirpt` will be built before the go test is built, and it will be made available to the test when the test is executed.

See https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go#how-do-i-access-testdata